# How to compare values in column A and, if same, compare adjacent values in column B to determine if they are the same?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have two columns, A and B, as seen below. I need a formula to check column A for identical values, such as all cells that contain A1. Then, any where A1 exists, I need it to check the adjacent cells in column B and make sure they match each other.

```
Column A|Column B
-----------------
   A1   |   1
   A1   |   1
   A1   |   2
   B1   |   1
   B1   |   1 
   B1   |   1
```

In the above example, the formula would see all three "A1" cells, then check column B for the adjacent cells and determine that the third "A1" cell has a different value, "2".

I've tried using a EXACT formula with a VLookup, but I can't get it to look at column B correctly.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will assume the first is correct and mark any different than the first in the list.

```
=IF(B1=VLOOKUP(A1,A:B,2,FALSE),"","Different")
```

[image]

---

This will mark all of the one that do not match:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,B1)<>COUNTIF(A:A,A1),"Error","")
```

[image]

---

This array formula marks any that are different than the modal value.

```
=IF(MODE.SNGL(IF($A$1:$A$6=A1,$B$1:$B$6))<>B1,"Different","")
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of 
Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Option A suits my needs better. Thank you very much!

Comment: See edit, the third uses the most frequent as the value and marks any that do not match that.